# Ionic detect iOS keychain open/close event?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Is there a way withing ionic framework to detect when a native ios modal such as the keychain modal opens or closes then run a function in response to that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by using the `cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard` plugin and some event listeners.

```
window.addEventListener('keyboardWillShow', (event: any) => {
  // Keyboard is showing
});

window.addEventListener('keyboardWillHide', (event: any) => {
  // Keyboard is hiding
});
```